# Is it possible to trigger the "do Select All" event with multiple events

Tags: event-triggers, iccube-reporting

In the icCube dashboards you can fire the event "do Select All" event in an icCube/Buttons widget. Unfortunately, you can only add one event as a trigger event.

Is it possible to trigger the event also with other events.

For example, you want that all buttons are selected if you change filters for:
- time
- product
etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can do that from the report javascript :

inside the :

```
function consumeEvent(context, event) {
```

catch your triggering event(s) :

```
if (event.name == '1st-triggering-event' || event.name == '2nd-triggering-event') {
```

then trigger what you want :

```
context.fireEvent("event-to-trigger", "mdx-value-to-select");
context.fireEvent("event-to-trigger2", "mdx-value-to-select2");
```